# scanNextInt() ignore empty lines

Tags: java

I use this code:

```
public String processFile(Scanner scanner) {
    String result = "";
    SumProcessor a = new SumProcessor();
    AverageProcessor b = new AverageProcessor();
    String line = null;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        if (scanner.hasNext("avg") == true) {

            c = scanner.next("avg");
           while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

                int j = scanner.nextInt();
                a.processNumber(j);
            }
           System.out.println("Exit a");
            result += a.getResult();
            a.reset();
        }
        if (scanner.hasNext("sum") == true) {

            c = scanner.next("sum");
           while(scanner.hasNextInt()){

          int j = scanner.nextInt();
                b.processNumber(j);                    
            }
            System.out.println("Exit b");
             result += b.getResult();
             b.reset();
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

And I need to end while cycle (hasNexInt()), when I press enter or send empty line.

I try use some methods with String == null e.t.c., but Java just IGNORE empty lines

**Output**

```
run:
avg
1
2
3
4

sum
Exit a
1
2
3
4
```

**but I need  :**

```
run:
avg
1
2
3
4

Exit a
sum    
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If usage of Scanner in your app is not absolute must, I can offer this:

```
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for(;;) {
    String lile = rdr.readLine();
    if (lile.trim().isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    // process your line
}
```

This code definitely stops on empty line from console. Now you can use Scanner for line processing or regex.

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like:

```
String line = null;
while(!(line = keyboard.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
// Your actions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `hasNextInt()` in your second `while` loop. The moment you do not pass an `int` value, the while loop will break.

Or you can also determine a specific value which you can pass to break the loop. For example, you can pass the character `'x'` and then check if 'x' is passed -> break the loop.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNext("avg") == true) {

            c = scanner.next("avg");
           while (scanner.hasNextInt()){ //THIS IS WHERE YOU USE hasNextInt()                       
                int j = scanner.scanNextInt();
                a.processNumber(j);
            }
           System.out.println("End While");
            result += a.getResult();
            a.reset();
        }
```

Comment: I try this :) See my FIXed code. But it is break only when I type `sum` after `avg`, or `avg` after `sum`

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin Did you try String.equals("")? I think i see what you are trying to do. Just input an empty string to the console input and then in your while loop check if your string EQUALS(""). If it is, then break the loop. Hope this info helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `scanner.nextLine()` to ignore the remaining entries in the line as:

```
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if("".equals(line)){
                   //exit out of the loop
                   break;
                }
                //assuming only one int in each line
                int j = Integer.parseInt(line);
                a.processNumber(j);
            }
```

Comment: I don't need ignore empty line, I need NOT ignore empty line

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin I meant, it will ignore the new line character which you entered along with nextInt(). I further improved the answer to read all `int` type inputs from the line before ignoring the new line character in the end.

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin Does it help or still there is issue? If there is issue, can you please highlight, what is not working?

Comment: I need to end While cycle INSIDE, because I process numbers after Inside WHILE break

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin But your `processNumber` method takes only one int as argument.

Comment: Yes, but I get **result** like this  `result += b.getResult(); b.reset();`

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin Did you try the approach I mentioned in the answer? I believe it should work or I am still not understanding your question.

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: I see, you wanted to terminate the `while` loop. I updated the answer with assumption that you will be entering one `int` in each line and `empty` line for loop termination. Please check and let me know.

Comment: `avg` next line `Exit a` When I press Enter, it immediately break while circle, before I enter some integer